# How to get the name of an OptionSet in Power Apps Portal with Liquid tags?

Tags: fetchxml, powerapps-portal

The result set below is the response from a fetchXML query.

```
<resultset morerecords="0" >
    <result/>
    <result>
        <trit_courseschedule name="Synchronous" formattedvalue="314310000" >
            314310000
        </trit_courseschedule>
    </result>
    <result>
        <trit_courseschedule name="Asynchronous" formattedvalue="314310001" >
            314310001
        </trit_courseschedule>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

How would you get the value of "name" from above result set? I did trit_courseschedule.name, but what it's supposed to be is trit_courseschedule.label, as you are getting the label of that option set. I wanted this to be out there for those who might have stumbled upon this issue like I did.

Answer (score 0):

The Option Set variable in Common Data Service is made of two attributes the value and the label.

- The Value is the internal Id each option in the set of options.
- The Label is the name assigned to each option in the set of options.

So in order to get to the Label with liquid tags you must use the following:

```
{{yourEntityVariable.yourOptionSetAttribute.Label}}
```